# Pine script question highest high versus highest close

Tags: pine-script, trading

I know that the script below will plot the highest high and lowest low, but how do I do the exact same kind of plot but using the highest bar/candle and lowest bar/candle?

If I just plot the close it will plot the bottom of a descending bar, and the top of an ascending. I want the top of either ascending or descending, and the bottom of either on two separate lines. Help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to figure this stuff out but I am struggling with this.

I really wish it had a var = highest bar (high, length)  function, that would make life simple

```
//@version=4

study("My Script",overlay=true)

lookbackres= input(3,title="Res Lookback")

lookbacksup= input(3,title="Sup Lookback")

res=highest(high,lookbackres)

sup=lowest(low,lookbacksup)

plot(series=res, color=color.green, linewidth=2)

plot(series=sup, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the min/max function to achieve that.

so in the end, your final code could look like this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
lookbackres= input(3,title="Res Lookback")
lookbacksup= input(3,title="Sup Lookback")
res=highest(max(open,close),lookbackres)
sup=lowest(min(open,close),lookbacksup)
plot(series=res, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(series=sup, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: why would you reinvent the wheel without additional functionality, when there is already a built-in `max` and `min` functions that do the same?

Comment: you are right. sorry didn't notice there are already built-in functions doing that. updated my answer now